# Stripping domain name from LoggedInTemplate in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a .Net 4 web app that uses Windows authentication and all works well however there is one trivial bug that is driving me nuts!

Visual Studio puts together the following for displaying who is logged in

```
 <LoggedInTemplate>
    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="http://somewhere/default.aspx"/> ]
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

The problem is though that this is displaying as `<domain>/user` rather than just the username which I am assuming it is pulling this value from

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

However I can't see anyway programtically to amend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix to it is to use a label in a place of the loginname control in your template. You can strip the domain from the User.Identity.Name and put the stripped version in a label. I had this problem too and I used the label (at least this is what I recall)

Comment: I like Rob's implementation/answer but for the simple application that this is I took your suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only inbuilt method of customising the output is the [`LoginName.FormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.formatstring.aspx) property, unfortunately all this allows is for you to provide a format string which the username gets embedded into, such as "Welcome, DOMAIN\NAME" rather than just "DOMAIN\NAME".

The only option I can see is to re-implement the LoginName control, either wholesale or by inheriting from `LoginName` and re-implementing the `RenderContents` method to format the username appropriately. From Reflector, the current code (for .net 2.0) for this is:

```
Protected Friend Overrides Sub RenderContents(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim userName As String = Me.UserName
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) Then
        userName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(userName)
        Dim formatString As String = Me.FormatString
        If (formatString.Length = 0) Then
            writer.Write(userName)
        Else
            Try 
                writer.Write(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, formatString, New Object() { userName }))
            Catch exception As FormatException
                Throw New FormatException(SR.GetString("LoginName_InvalidFormatString"), exception)
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

`UserName` is a `Friend ReadOnly` property of the LoginName class which, via another internal class called LoginUtil gets the username from `HttpContext.Current.User`.